# How to serialize a Predicate<T> from Nashorn engine in java 8

Tags: serialization, java-8, predicate, nashorn

How can i serialize a predicate obtained from java ScriptEngine nashorn? or how can i cast jdk.nashorn.javaadapters.java.util.function.Predicate to Serializable?

Here is the case:

I have this class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Filter implements Serializable {

    private Predicate<Object> filter;

    public Predicate<Object> getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    public void setFilter(Predicate<Object> filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    public boolean evaluate(int value) {
        return filter.test(value);
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class TestFilterSer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        Filter f = new Filter();
        //This works
        //f.setFilter(getCastedPred());

        // But I want this to work
        f.setFilter(getScriptEnginePred());

        System.out.println(f.evaluate(6));

        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("pred.ser")))) {
            oos.writeObject(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        f= null;

        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("pred.ser")))) {
            f= (Filter)ois.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(f.evaluate(7));
    }

    public static Predicate<Object> getCastedPred() {
        Predicate<Object> isEven = (Predicate<Object> & Serializable)(i) -> (Integer)i%2 == 0;
        return isEven;
    }


    public static Predicate<Object> getScriptEnginePred() throws ScriptException {

        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");

        Predicate<Object> p =  (Predicate<Object> & Serializable)engine.eval(
                    String.format("new java.util.function.Predicate(%s)", "function(i) i%2==0")
                );

        return p;
    }
}
```

**Requirement**: To be able to serialize the Predicate obtained from Nashorn engine.

**Observation**: When I get Predicate from method getCastedPred(). It works because it is `java.util.function.Predicate`. it does Serialize after casting to `Serializable`. But when I get the Predicate from the Nashorn engine, Internally it returns me the `jdk.nashorn.javaadapters.java.util.function.Predicate` this one doesn't Serialize and **casting** to `Serializable` doesn't work.

Any idea how can i serialize this type of Predicate?

Comment: It’s up to whoever uses Nashorn to detach its serialized form from the unserializable Nashorn components. This is completely unrelated to the code you have posted, which doesn’t use Nashorn at any place.

Comment: Predicate is assigned an object from engine.eval() method from ScriptEngine

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your API uses Predicate, not AggregateFilter.  So the target type for the lambda in

```
setAggregatePredicate(x -> true)
```

will be `Predicate`, not `AggregateFilter` -- and the compiler won't know to make it serializable.  If you change your API to use the more specific functional interface, serializable lambdas will be generated.

Comment: I have edited the question to exact problem with running example. What I understand now is Predicate returned by Nashorn is not serializable.

Comment: Yes, Nashorn objects are not serializable (by design!)

Comment: Okay, is there a workaround to cast it to java.util.function.Predicate by introspecting or somehow to make it serializable?

Comment: @Ajeetkumar No.  And this really has nothing to do with lambdas -- it's a property of serialization in general.   If an object is created whose runtime class does not extend Serializable, there's no way to make it serializable.  And whether a lambda instance implements Serializable or not is a property of its capture site.  So if it's not born serializable, that's the end of the story.