# How to share data among JavaRDD partitions in Spark?

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark

I have Some object to be shared among partitions in apache spark. Below is the code snippet and problem i'm facing.

```
private static void processDataWithResult() throws IOException {

        JavaRDD<Long> idRDD = createIdRDDUsingDb();
        final MeasureReportingData measureReporingData = getMeasureReportingData(jobConfiguration);

        resultRDD = idRDD.mapPartitions(new FlatMapFunction<Iterator<Long>, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Iterable<Boolean> call(Iterator<Long> idIterator) throws Exception {

                MeasureReportingData mrd = measureReporingData; 

                final List<Boolean> dummyList = new ArrayList<>();

                long minId = idIterator.next();

                engine.processInBatch(minId, minId + BATCH_SIZE - 1);
                return (Iterable<Boolean>) dummyList;
            }
        });

        resultRDD.count();

    }
```

I want to distribute `measureReportingData` object to all the partitions?

I get serialization errors because `MeasureReportingData` contains instance members that are not `Serializable`. Simulation of the issue is specified in this question: [How to serialize a Predicate<T> from Nashorn engine in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243299/how-to-serialize-a-predicatet-from-nashorn-engine-in-java-8)

Is there another way to share measureReportingData among partitions?

Answer (score 1):

In order to share data between machines, the data has to be serialized at the source, transfer over network, and de-serialized at the destination. So you cannot transfer non-serializable objects.

If `MeasureReportingData` is not serializable, you have to convert it into a serializable object, share that object then convert it back to `MeasureReportingData` inside the function.

Comment: Ok, looks like Serialization is the way. I know it'll work if MeasureReportingData is Serializable. but the problem i'm facing is mentioned in the link to Serialize a Predicate<T> from Nashorn, any thought on that?

Comment: You simply cannot share non-serializable objects. There's no way around that.

Comment: @Dikei Well, you can always not share but initialize in place.

Comment: That's true. I'm suggesting him doing just that in my answer.